# How to animate a d3 js v4 bar chart from bottom(x axis) to up?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Currently, this d3 js bar chart animates from top to bottom. Most likely its because of the way d3js renders its chart which starts from the top.  This might be a common issue and might be easy for those who are familiar with the nuisance of d3js, how can I make this animate from bottom to top?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="1260" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.4),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]); 

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("MRT_MonthlyAve_2014.csv", function(d) {

  d.MonthlyAverage = +d.MonthlyAverage;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Station; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.MonthlyAverage; })]);

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")    
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(12, "s"))
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar") 
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Station); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.MonthlyAverage); }) 
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .ease(d3.easeExp)
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())   
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.MonthlyAverage); });
});


</script>
```

MRT_MonthlyAve_2014.csv

```
Station,MonthlyAverage
North Avenue,2227081
Quezon Avenue,1018121
GMA,606110
Cubao,1410788
Santolan,260737
Ortigas,561910
Shaw Boulevard,1339020
Boni,631115
Guadalupe,1002740
Buendia,421302
Ayala,1145004
Magallanes,933713
Taft Avenue,2427220
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set the initial `y` position to `height`:

```
.attr("y", height)
```

Here is your code with that change only (I'm reducing the height of the SVG, so you can see it working in the small snippet view):

```js
var csv = `Station,MonthlyAverage
North Avenue,2227081
Quezon Avenue,1018121
GMA,606110
Cubao,1410788
Santolan,260737
Ortigas,561910
Shaw Boulevard,1339020
Boni,631115
Guadalupe,1002740
Buendia,421302
Ayala,1145004
Magallanes,933713
Taft Avenue,2427220`;

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.4),
  y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d.MonthlyAverage = +d.MonthlyAverage;
  return d;
})

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.Station;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.MonthlyAverage;
})]);

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(12, "s"))
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", "0.71em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");

g.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.Station);
  })
  .attr("y", height)
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .ease(d3.easeExp)
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.MonthlyAverage);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.MonthlyAverage);
  });
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1260" height="200"></svg>
```